# Deducing results about continuous time random walks from the corresponding discrete time result

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, markov-process

Is there any standard way to prove results about continuous time random walks from the corresponding results for discrete time random walks?

Specifically, my problem is that I was reading Lawler and Limic's Random Walk: A Modern Introduction and there is a result that bounds the transition probability which feels like is should be true still for continuous time random walks.

The result states $\exists c>0$ such that $\forall x,n$

$$p_n(x)\leq\frac{c}{n^{d/2}}.
$$

So my question is, can this be used to deduce the analogous result with a continuous time parameter $t$ in place of $n$?

Comment: Indeed, since, for every $t$, $$p^{\mathrm{cont}}_t(\ )=e^{-t}\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{t^n}{n!}p^{\mathrm{disc}}_n(\ ).$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So for example in 2 dimensions

$$p^{cont}_t(x)=e^{-t}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^n}{n!}p^{disc}_n(x)\leq ce^{-t}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^n}{n!n}$$

I don't see how to progress to conclude $$p^{cont}_t(x)\leq \frac{c}{t}$$

Maybe I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: Perhaps this is it:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^n}{n!n}=\frac{1}{t}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^{n+1}}{n!n}=\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{s^n}{n!}ds=\frac{e^t}{t}.
$$

Comment: No the sum of the series is not what you say but, using $n\geqslant\frac12(n+1)$ for every $n\geqslant1$, one sees that $p_n^{\mathrm{disc}}(x)\leqslant c/n$ for every $n\geqslant1$ yields, for every $t\gt0$, $$p_t^{\mathrm{cont}}(x)\leqslant e^{-t}(1+2ce^t/t)=(2c/t)+e^{-t}.$$

Answer (score -1):

You can discretize a continuous 1- dimensional random walk $X_t$: 
let $p=\mathbb P(X_t \mbox {hits 1 before hitting -1}|X_0=0)$ and $q=1-p$. Define a 
simple discrete random walk $Y_n$ with transition probabilities p and q. 
This gives you $t_1<t_2<..$ such that $X_{t_n}=Y_n$ and some version of the mentioned result must hold for $X_t$.

I think I read this in Durrett's "Probability theory and applications".